# RoR UI & WebService: working around protect_from_forgery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, rest

I would like to use my RoR application to handle both UI and ReSTful API requests, however
I'm running into problems because of the `protect_from_forgery` flag. I don't want the API user to have to store a cookie or have to pass an `authenticity_token`; and, I want to be able to use the same ReSTful queries for both the UI and the API. For example,

```
https://host.domain.com/user/show/1
https://host.domain.com/user/create
```

The application controller would need to check if an API call is being made and then
not call the `protect_from_forgery` flag. So something like:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :api
```

But here `:api` is an action and I would need to map a new route. I don't think this would allow me to use the same controllers and actions as the UI.

So I'm confused and unsure how to approach this problem. Surely this is a common issue
that many others have had to solve. I appreciate any help that folks could provide.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a yucky idea: skip the before filter, for all actions. Then add a new filter

```
def verify_authenticity_token_or_api
  api? || verify_authenticity_token
end
```

In your `api` method, work out whether the request is an api request. Be careful to not allow people to bypass forgery protection by making requests that look a bit like api requests - you might want to do something like invalidate the user's session if there is something that looks like a api request.

Another approach is just to have dedicated endpoints and controllers for your apis. While the stuff rails gets you for free is appealing, sometimes the resources you want to expose don't correspond exactly to your models

Comment: Your suggestion worked wonderfully. I really appreciate the help. I could not find an answer anywhere. I would think that a lot of people have come across this before and had to work out a solution. Again, thanks much!